# PHP if name appears more than once in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I would like to determine if the same team name (that is outputted with the variables `$home_team['team_name']` and `$away_team['team_name']`) appears more than once inside the

```
if ($game_date_converted == $next_monday)
```

statement.

If the team name does appear more than once (for example, if it appears twice), I would like that text to be displayed in RED.

In plain English, for the list of games, if the team name (which could be either home team or away team) appears twice show that team name in RED.

Thank you for your help!

```
<?php foreach ($games as $game) { ?>

<?php

$team_id = $game['home_team_id'];
$home_team = sw::shared()->teams->getForID($team_id); 

$away_team_id = $game['away_team_id'];
$away_team = sw::shared()->teams->getForID($away_team_id); 

$leagues = sw::shared()->packages->getAll(); 

$game_date = $game['date'];
$game_date_converted = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($game_date));

$date_converted = date('l', strtotime($game_date));
?>

<?php if ($game_date_converted == $next_monday) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $home_team['team_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $away_team['team_name']; ?></td>


    <!-- more HTML -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusted it again. No problem !!
All rendered teams have a span with a class, so they can be read out with javascript. I then read the text content in them and put that in an array and see if I have multiple values. If yes, I look for all the ones in the HTML that gave me a double content and add a class to them.

```
<?php echo "<td><span class='team'>" . $home_team['team_name'] . "</span></td>"; ?>
<?php echo "<td><span class='team'>" . $away_team['team_name'] . "</span></td>"; ?>

  $(document).ready(function () {
            var teams = Array();
            $(".team").each(function () {

                teams.push($(this).text());

            });
            teams.sort();

            for (var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {

                if (teams[i] === teams[i + 1]) {

                    $(".team").each(function () {

                        if ($(this).text() == teams[i]) {
                            $(this).addClass("doubleteam");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        });
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/TNAGr/37/

This runs through your schedule display for that day and looks for doubles teams. If it find them, it will add the class "doubleteam". You can style this class to your desire in the CSS stylesheet. Further you can also style your team names as a whole in the CSS sheet.
I hope this is exactly what your looking

Comment: Thanks for the updated solution. But you see, the team names are different.. it's displaying a game schedule on a specific day so there are multiple team names. For example, one team could be "Hawks" and the other could be "Jets"... so if the home team name "Hawks" appears twice show that team name in red but not the team name "Jets" unless it appears twice also. I think there should be some php involved? thanks again

Comment: can anyone help me with this?

Comment: OK ... You got multiple game events to show on one day. If a team plays more than once on that day, you want it red. Is that correctly translated?

Comment: Altered the code and the fiddle. Try again and see if that works out for you. :-) ... If it is, please mark this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks! It's perfect except I'm using ajax links to load schedules for different days on the page... how can I make the jQuery read again after the content is refreshed? I tried to set it to run on click for each link with no luck.

Comment: You can call your ajax with an interval, but that is a different topic than your initial question.
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/ajax-update-content-every-x-seconds.html

Comment: I see what you're saying. Is there a way to convert that window.load /document ready function into a standalone function that can be used with an interval? Thank you SO much for your help again.

Comment: Yes you can. A simple adjustment in fiddle can put it all into its own function: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/TNAGr/38/

Comment: If you do Ajax, then you will need to repopulate all the data. That means that you will need identifiers all around to target the correct table cells. You may want to consider to do an auto refresh on your page. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp
Or set a flag in your php for ajax to read and do a page refresh through javascript with `location.reload();`

Comment: Thank you again Daniel! I put setInterval( "searchDoubles()", 100 ); and then used PHP to only run that full code on the desired page.

Comment: An interval of 100 seems quite intensive. That is once every 100ms.
Also be aware of the setInterval method. They can stack, unless you clear it with clearInteval: http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/client-object-property-method/window-setinterval.php
You basically only need to run it once upon a data refresh, ie a page refresh or ajax data update. Good luck! :)

Comment: And as you're on your way, you can close this thread by accepting an answer. Until we meet again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to style the way it is displayed, you may want to add a classname (yourclass) to the parsing of the teams and then apply css.

```
<td><?php echo "<span class='home-team'>" . $home_team['team_name'] . "</span>"; ?></td>
<td><?php echo "<span class='away-team'>" . $away_team['team_name'] . "</span>"; ?></td>
```

In the head section you can add your jquery library:

Then add the jquery script:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".home-team").not(":first").css("color","red");
        $(".away-team").not(":first").css("color","red");
   });
```

Best to see this in a live situation, so I createed a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/TNAGr/13/

Comment: Hi .. sorry for a later response.
Yes, with adding a classname you are able to select specifically on the elements carrying that class. As such you can select the second one with CSS. Consequently you can turn it reverse. Since you want all others to be red. I will edit the code to reflect more specifically what you are looking for..

Comment: On second thought, after a quick test, I found out that the nth-child selector does not appear to work on the span element. However, if you are able to apply some javascript, you can do this quite simply with jquery. Again I adjusted the code....

Comment: Thanks very much for all your help with this. The only adjustment is that the first should also be in red. Basically what I'm trying to do here is show the teams that have a double header (meaning two games) in red. So, if the same team name appears more than once, show the team name in red every time it appears. Thanks again